# How to make MySQL 8 alert when integer overflow happens during INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, error-handling, integer

Let's consider we have a simple table with auto-incrementing integer `ID` and some unique column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `value` (`value`)
);
```

Imagine we inserted into it so many times that `ID` reached the maximum:

```sql
INSERT INTO test VALUES 
(4294967294, 1),
(4294967295, 2);
```

Now we are trying to insert one more row and if it's duplicate then change the `value` to 3:

```sql
INSERT INTO test (`value`) VALUES (1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value` = 3;
```

**What is the expected behaviour?**

```
        id     value  
----------  --------
4294967294         3
4294967295         2
```

**What we get in fact:**

```
        id     value  
----------  --------
4294967294         1
4294967295         3
```

**How?** Because of the integer overflow the auto-generated `ID` of the new row was again 4294967295.

**So now the question. Is it possible to make MySQL 8 alert if the overflow happens during query?** In my case such silent overflow caused huge data loss. Because all newly added rows just overwrote the last row.

PS I'm not asking how to fix or prevent such overflow. That's obvious. I'm asking exactly how to catch such errors.

Comment: what sql_mode you configured ?    If it is not strict, try  strict sql mode. 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict

Comment: @User2397, my mode was `NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`. Just tried adding `STRICT_ALL_TABLES`. Nothing changed :(

Comment: MariaDB, at least back to 10.0.28, gives this error:  `Out of range value for column 'id' at row 1 [in prepared statement]`

Answer (score 1):

USE a BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER to check for all fields where you can reach their limits.

With the newest mysql incarnation you can actually can use the [CKECK CONSTRAINT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) to 
prevent an INSERT at all, but with the TRIGGER you can manage and define What to do

Answer (score 0):

I guess I would argue that it did "a right thing".

Note:  You have two `UNIQUE` keys.  On the surface, IODKU should check both keys in order to find the *up to two* rows to modify.

However, since IODKU is "either update (first priority) or insert (if row does not exist)" then let's consider this algorithm:

1. Check all `UNIQUE` keys other than `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  After all, you did not explicitly specify `id`.  So, one can argue that only one row is checked.
2. If found (`value=1`) then `UPDATE`.
3. If not found, *then* do the insert.  Only now does the auto_inc get involved.

In your test case, *Oracle, but not MariaDB* seems to

1. Cap the overflow at 4294967295
2. Decide *that row* (not the other row) is a dup, so UPDATE it.

Suggest you file a bug with bugs.mysql.com  I checked 5.5 through 8.0.16.

(I looked for, but without success, the MariaDB fix that caused them to diverge, possibly in 5.5 or before.)